# ANSI escapes don't work in `printf`

Tags: bash, printf, sh, ansi-colors

When trying to use [ANSI color escapes from a shell script](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html), I was completely stuck, as the escape sequences (`\e`) were printed verbatim to the output.

```
#!/bin/sh
GREEN="\e[32m"
RED="\e[31m"
CLEAR="\e[0m"
printf "${GREEN}test passed${CLEAR}\n"
printf "${RED}test failed${CLEAR}\n"
```

Produces

```
\e[32mtest passed\e[0m
\e[31mtest failed\e[0m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\e` is not recognized by POSIX `sh` (as mentioned by honzasp), but `\033` is.

```
GREEN='\033[32m'
CLEAR='\033[0m'
printf "${GREEN}testpassed${CLEAR}\n"
```

Generally, it's safer to not expand parameters inside the first argument to `printf` (consider, for example `FOO="hello %s"; printf "$FOO bar \n" baz;`). However, this requires you to embed an *actual* escape character in your parameters, rather than a string that `printf` interprets as an escape character.

```
GREEN=$(printf '\033[32m')
CLEAR=$(printf '\033[0m')
printf '%stest passed%s' "$GREEN" "$CLEAR"
```

Comment: `GREEN=$(printf '\033[32m')` can be written as `printf -v GREEN '\033[32m')` for efficiency (it avoids a subshell being forked). Same thing for `CLEAR` as well.

Comment: `printf -v` isn't part of the POSIX shell specification, though.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` in the first line, because raw `sh`'s `printf` doesn't understand the escapes.

Comment: I spent ages trying to find this out for the first time, and now it bit me again, so I decided to avoid the experience for the next time :)

Comment: On Linux there's also an external command `printf(1)`, so calling the external command with a full path might work too: `/usr/bin/printf "..."` (assuming `printf(1)` actually lives in `/usr/bin` on your system).